# Writing your own spree static content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Is it possible to display spree_static_content by creating a html.erb file in the app directory instead of using the pages tab in the admin page.

Comment: You can do what you can do with simple rails application but in this case that will be static . you have to create method , page and route own your own. Here static means you could not manage from admin and if you wand that to then you have to write code for that inside admin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create your own static file. If the file is a `view` file then name it same as the file in spree under the `view->spree` directory. You need to use `decorators` if you need to override `models` or `controllers`.